# Triggering function when post is published

Tags: php, wordpress, function, email

Problem: Making easy to send job list newsletter

My solution: Register custom post type and than sending it's content to users when post is published

There are two kind of mails:

1. first for sending all jobs to people who didn't specify job field
2. second for sending specific jobs (example: costumer applied to frontend position and checked to get monthly email with similar jobs)

There are two custom WYSWYG fields made with ACF for that purpose (one for each email)

I made a function `kandidati_send_newsletter()` which does all the job and it works. I am sure that it works and I tested it. So now I want to trigger that function when that custom post is published.

This how I done it:

```
    function run_when_poslovi_newsletter_published($ID, $post) {
    $posttype = 'poslovi-newsletter';

    if ($post->post_type == $posttype) {
        kandidati_send_newsletter();
    }
}
add_action('publish_post', 'run_when_poslovi_newsletter_published');
```

But it doesn't send mails when I publish post. I am not sure why but I think it doesn't trigger function at all.

Thanks

Comment: What do you get if you debug the values in the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found solution :)

Just needed to add custom post type at the end of publish, like this:

```
function run_when_poslovi_newsletter_published($ID, $post) {

   kandidati_send_newsletter();

}
add_action('publish_poslovi-newsletter', 'run_when_poslovi_newsletter_published', 10, 2);
```